# Excluding inner hits from top hits aggregation with source filter

Tags: elasticsearch

In my query, I am using the `inner_hits` to return the list of nested objects that match my query.

I then add an aggregations for categoryId of my document, and then a top hit aggregation to get the display name for that category.

```
"aggs": {
  "category": {
    "terms": {
      "field": "categoryId",
      "size": 100
    },
    "aggs": {
      "category_value": {
        "top_hits": {
          "size": 1,
          "_source": {
            "includes": "categoryName"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, when I look at the aggregation buckets, I do get a `_source` document with only the `categoryName` property, but I also get the entire `inner_hits` collection:

```
{
    ...
    "_source": {
        "categoryName": "Armchairs"
    },
    "inner_hits": {
        "my_inner_hits": {
            "hits": {
                "total": 260,
                "max_score": null,
                "hits": [{
                        ...
                        "_source": {
                            //nested document here
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to not include the `inner_hits` data in a `top_hits` aggregation?

Comment: Hello, could you add your whole query and some example documents, please? It's hard to understand what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Since you only need a single field, what I suggest you to do is to get rid of `top_hits` aggregation and use another `terms` aggregation for the name:

```
{
  ...
  "aggs": {
    "category": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "categoryId",
        "size": 100
      },
      "aggs": {
        "category_value": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "categoryName",
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That will also be a little bit more efficient.

**UPDATE**:

Another way to keep using `terms/top_hits` is to leverage [response filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#common-options-response-filtering) and only return what you need. For instance, appending this to your URL will make sure that you won't find any inner hits inside your aggregation

```
?filter_path=hits.hits,aggregations.**.key,aggregations.**.doc_count,aggregations.**.hits.hits.hits._source
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This is a simplified example, so I am wondering how efficient this would be if I needed for example 10 fields from my top_hit?

Comment: I'd say it would be a different use case. What is yours exactly?

Comment: We have a product index, where each product document has a list of nested variants. When I make a query, I use inner_hits to know which of the variants actually matched my query. Now, if I make a top_hit aggregation, then the inner_hits will always be part of that top hit, which increases the size of the response by a lot if there are a lot of terms in the aggregation.

Comment: Yes, I understood that part. The solution I'm suggesting gets rid of that issue.

Comment: Well, adding another term aggregation for each field that I want from the top_hit does not scale very well. If I want to get 20 fields from a variant, then I need 20 term aggregations?

Comment: Again, that wasn't mentioned in your initial problem statement :-) It looked like you only needed the category name, which makes sense if you aggregate on `categoryId`. Are you sure that your 20 other fields are unique per category?

Comment: Yes, the fields for a category would be the same one all products. They are just indexed on each product for easy access. That is why the top_hits is a perfect match, if it was not for the issue when combined with inner_hits.

Comment: Ok, I have a PoC working with the filter_path now. Even though that feels like a hack. 

Do you know if this purely affects the data that gets sent over the wire? I imagine that the top_hit is still gathering the information behind the scenes, and we are simply hiding it from the json?

Comment: Well, it's not really a hack per se. Inner hits have to be computed/gathered anyway since you're retrieving hits from your query. What happens for `top_hits` is that the aggregation engine is re-using the hits from the query, so I would say there's not much more work involved. The fact that you see `inner_hits` in aggregations without asking for them means that they are already present somewhere and not filtered out from aggregations, so there is not more job involved behind the scenes, but less.

Comment: If I'm only asking for 20 results, and the top hit is not present in the top 20, then I assume extra gathering will occur? Either way, this would certainly be a way to reduce the bandwidth needed for the results.