# Is it possible to remove the doc_count and more from Composite Aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, composite

I use an ElasticSearch search request with composite aggregation in order to get a list of all different indexed values of one specific field.
The result gives me all I need, but I don't need all that info contained.

Request:

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "my_buckets": {
            "composite": {
                "size": 10000,
                "sources": [{
                        "my_stoid": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "stoId"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 0
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "took": 4,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 15,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "composite#my_buckets": {
            "after_key": {
                "my_stoid": "KV"
            },
            "buckets": [{
                    "key": {
                        "my_stoid": "1"
                    },
                    "doc_count": 5
                }, {
                    "key": {
                        "my_stoid": "2102"
                    },
                    "doc_count": 1
                }, {
                    "key": {
                        "my_stoid": "8000"
                    },
                    "doc_count": 1
                }, {
                    "key": {
                        "my_stoid": "9999"
                    },
                    "doc_count": 6
                }, {
                    "key": {
                        "my_stoid": "KB"
                    },
                    "doc_count": 1
                }, {
                    "key": {
                        "my_stoid": "KV"
                    },
                    "doc_count": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I only need the values "1", "2102", "8000"... from the buckets.
Like so:

```
    "buckets": ["1", "2102", "8000", "9999", "KB", "KV"]
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: This thread might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59212580/4604579 (hint: use `filter_path`)

Comment: @Val By adding the query ?filter_path=aggregations.**.my_stoid to the request I only receive the "aggregations". And also the "doc_count" values are removed.
It's not exactly what I wanted, but it reduces the response a lot. Many thanks :-)